# localhost and 127.0.0.1 are redirecting - how?

Tags: macos, homebrew, httpd, macos-highsierra

On macOS High Sierra 10.13.3 - I switched from using built in apachectl/httpd, to using Homebrew installed version.

For some reason, 127.0.0.1 and localhost both redirect to a local.dev hostname, which loads a site in a sub-directory of my web root.

I have tried:

1. Clearing out /etc/hosts
2. Disabling all htaccess files in directories that I use
3. Clearing and restarting local DNS cache
4. Different browsers (all behave the same)
5. Removing all default apache startup/launch processes/daemons
6. Removing homebrew's httpd launch item so I can enable it manually

For the life of me I cannot access the directory that I point to in httpd.conf as my web root. Typing in 127.0.0.1 and/or localhost always redirects me to local.dev

I'm at a loss.

Comment: can you open a shell and type in "cat /etc/hosts" once more? It should not be empty, rather it should contain "127.0.0.1 localhost
255.255.255.255 broadcasthost
::1             localhost"

Comment: Also "cat /private/etc/hosts".